# SystemVerilog: unbased unsized literal in Concatenation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I assume that when placing an unbased, unsized literal on the left-most side of a concatenation will simply fill in any missing bits with the given value. I didn't see anything explicitly stating this in the LRM.

```
logic [63:0] rd_data;
logic [31:0] mem_dout;
logic [15:0] op_data;
....
assign rd_data = {'0, op_data, mem_dout};
```

Obviously, the following would be **illegal**:

Edit: As @dave_59 pointed out, this is legal, just not intuitive.

```
assign rd_data = {op_data, mem_dout, '0};
```

Just wanted to check if anyone knows that (1) this simulates as expected, and (2) the major synthesis tools do the correct thing and tie the upper 16 bits to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both statements are legal. In a self-determined context `'0` is equivalent to `1'b0`. All the operands of a concatenation evaluate in a self-determined context. The result of both concatenations is a 32+16+1=49-bit expression. In the context of the assignment to rd_data, those expressions get right-aligned, and then left padded with 15 zeros.

So you get the result you are expecting, but for an entirely different reason.

Comment: Is the padding based on the value of the upper-most bit provided or does Verilog always 0-pad?

Comment: Unsigned data is always 0-padded. Signed data is sign extended to the width of the signed context.